# SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow Not Generating Task

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, workflow-tasks-list

I have developed a project site workflow in SPD that moves the project through various phases and stages. At the beginning of each stage, the workflow assigns a task to the project owner. In some instances (it works most of the time), when applying the workflow to an existing project site and skipping to a specific stage, the workflow is not generating the task.

[image: Workflow stage example]

For the life of me, I can not figure out what the issue is. Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Are your log messages showing up? Maybe add a debug message either side of your task creation step to see if that part of the stage is executing

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I did add the debug messages before and after the task creation step, which clarified my issue. I don't think it is the task creation step that is causing the issue, rather it is the 'Set the current project stage status.' Any ideas?

Comment: This is the error message:
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to https://amicamutual.sharepoint.com/sites/PWALifeProd/_api/ProjectServer/WorkflowActivities/UpdateProjectStageStatus(projectId='a2e84761-1527-e511-80cf-00155dac3713',stageId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',statusInformation=@statusInfo,stageStatusValue='1',append='False')?%40statusInfo='Pending+Post+Deployment+&+Closing' Correlation Id: ff74a948-1076-78bf-bdab-69f57c6d40fc Instance Id: a5b6975c-cf1d-40b6-a9fc-061db797e2b5

Comment: Not sure, sorry! Looks to be Project Server related though (not just SharePoint), and I'm not super familiar with the workflow activities specific to project server.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up removing the 'Set the current project stage status' event and the workflow runs perfectly.

Comment: Cool, you should add that as an answer

Comment: I am new to this web forum and forgot to mark it as an answer. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be Project Server related error (not just SharePoint). I ended up removing the 'Set the current project stage status' event and the workflow runs perfectly.